# Unable to do payment in angular cordova app from android device

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, razorpay

When I try to do payment from my angular cordova app through razorpay payment gateway in android device, it shows white blank screen without any error in console of devTools.

I tried to implement https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova suggestion and implementation method, but can't find the solution for the issue.